# Why django and python MySQLdb have one cursor per database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

Example scenario:

MySQL running a single server -> HOSTNAME

Two MySQL databases on that server -> USERS ,  GAMES .

Task -> Fetch 10 newest games from GAMES.my_games_table ,  and fetch users playing those games from USERS.my_users_table ( assume no joins )

In Django as well as Python MySQLdb , why is having one cursor for each database more preferable ?

What is the disadvantage of an extended cursor which is single per MySQL server and can switch databases ( eg by querying "use USERS;" ), and then work on corresponding database

MySQL connections are cheap, but isn't single connection better than many , if there is a linear flow and no complex tranasactions which might need two cursors ?

Comment: Django supports multiple database connections - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: @JonathanVanasco Yes, that is exactly my question, why should there be two connections for 2 databases located on SAME SERVER .
eg. in settings.py I would have to define both USERS and GAMES, and django will make 2 connections instead of one.

Comment: @dm03514 That is an example scenario. Assume logical shards, or read only slave of some other database. Bottom line is, multiple databases on single mysql instance.

Comment: I see. I interpreted your question wrong. I think its because of the DB API Specification:  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects """These objects represent a database cursor, which is used to manage the context of a fetch operation. Cursors created from the same connection are not isolated, i.e., any changes done to the database by a cursor are immediately visible by the other cursors. Cursors created from different connections can or can not be isolated, depending on how the transaction support is implemented (see also the connection's .rollback() and .commit() methods)."""

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A shorter answer would be, "MySQL doesn't support that type of cursor", so neither does Python-MySQL, so the reason one connection command is preferred is because that's the way MySQL works. Which is sort of a tautology.

However, the longer answer is:

1. A 'cursor', by your definition, would be some type of object accessing tables and indexes within an RDMS, capable of maintaining its state.
2. A 'connection', by your definition, would accept commands, and either allocate or reuse a cursor to perform the action of the command, returning its results to the connection.
3. By your definition, a 'connection' would/could manage multiple cursors.
4. You believe this would be the preferred/performant way to access a database as 'connections' are expensive, and 'cursors' are cheap.

However:

1. A `cursor` in MySQL (and other RDMS) is not a the user-accessible mechanism for performing operations. MySQL (and other's) perform operations in as "set", or rather, they compile your SQL command into an internal list of commands, and do numerous, complex bits depending on the nature of your SQL command and your table structure.
2. A `cursor` is a specific mechanism, utilized within stored procedures (and there only), giving the developer a way to work with data in a procedural way.
3. A 'connection' in MySQL is what you think of as a 'cursor', sort of. MySQL does not expose it's internals for you as an iterator, or pointer, that is merely moving over tables. It exposes it's internals as a 'connection' which accepts SQL and other commands, translates those commands into an internal action, performs that action, and returns it's result to you.
4. This is the difference between a 'set' and a 'procedural' execution style (which is really about the granularity of control you, the user, is given access to, or at least, the granularity inherent in how the RDMS abstracts away its internals when it exposes them via an API).

Answer (score 2):

As you say, MySQL connections are cheap, so for your case, I'm not sure there is a technical advantage either way, outside of code organization and flow. It might be easier to manage two cursors than to keep track of which database a single cursor is currently talking to by painstakingly tracking SQL 'USE' statements. Mileage with other databases may vary -- remember that Django strives to be database-agnostic.

Also, consider the case where two different databases, even on the same server, require different access credentials. In such a case, two connections will be necessary, so that each connection can successfully authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

One cursor per database is not necessarily preferable, it's just the default behavior.

The rationale is that different databases are more often than not on different servers, use different engines, and/or need different initialization options. (Otherwise, why should you be using different "databases" in the first place?)

In your case, if your two databases are just namespaces of tables (what should be called "schemas" in SQL jargon) but reside on the same MySQL instance, then by all means use a single connection. (How to configure Django to do so is actually an altogether different question.)

You are also right that a single connection is better than two, if you only have a single thread and don't actually need two database workers at the same time.